# Write dynamical arrays in Fortran 90

Tags: arrays, formatting, fortran, output, fortran90

I have arrays with dynamical dimension (`dimx`, `dim`) and I need a way to write such arrays in a file through the `Write` instruction, the problem is that until now I haven't been able to produce such files in a automatic way, I mean until now I have to change the dimension of the array in the `Write` instruction by hand and I need a way in which the dimension change depending of the dimension `dimx` and `dim` in the way:

```
integer :: dimx, dim 
complex, allocatable :: matA(:,:), vectB(:)

 allocate(matA(dimx,dimx), vectB(dim))  

write(1,'(**dimx** e16.6) matA
write(2,'(**dim** e16.6) vecB
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please always use tag [tag:fortran] for Firtran questions. You can add a specific version tag, but it is only supplementary. Others, please do the retagging too, when I do that myself, I lose the ability to close duplicates (although that might be a good thing depending on my ability to judge).

Answer (score 3):

The repeat-count on a format specifier in an I/O statement is not necessarily the dimension of an array in the data-list. It is entirely legal for several distinct data items to correspond to a single repeated format specifier like:

```
 write(unit,'(3f5.1)') x,y,z
```

or for an array to correspond to several different format specifiers:

```
 real::a(3)
 write(unit,'(f5.1,f10.2,f5.1)') a
```

And if there are more format specifiers than needed for the data-list (which can be variable using dynamic bounds and/or implied-do), including but not limited to repeated specifiers, the extra are ignored. Thus **the traditional way** (back to F66 at least) to handle a variable number of data items (in one dimension) is to use a 'huge' repeat count that is at least as large as the data ever is.

Your arrays are of `complex` elements, so each element is actually **two** values and the format repeat must be at least twice the number of elements.

**Since F77** the format can be a character variable and you can set the value of that (or any other) character variable with an 'internal' WRITE, which allows constructing and using a data-dependent format. This method allows you to tailor the format for a 2-D array to one (exact) dimension.

An example showing both of these methods for your case:

```
program SO43482939
integer,parameter::dimx=2,dimy=3,dim=4
complex,allocatable::mata(:,:),vecb(:)
character(len=80)::fmt
integer i,j
allocate (mata(dimx,dimy),vecb(dim))
do i=1,dimx
  do j=1,dimy
    mata(i,j)=complex(i*10+j,i*10+j)
  end do
end do
do i=1,dim
  vecb(i)=complex(i*10+j,i*10+j)
end do
write(*,'(999f5.1)') vecb
write(fmt,'(a,i5,a)') '(',2*dimx,'f5.1)'
write(*,'(a)') fmt
write(*,fmt) mata
end program

OUTPUT

 14.0 14.0 24.0 24.0 34.0 34.0 44.0 44.0
(    4f5.1)
 11.0 11.0 21.0 21.0
 12.0 12.0 22.0 22.0
 13.0 13.0 23.0 23.0
```

Answer (score 3):

To supplement the other answer, and a matter not covered in the near-duplicate referred to in the comments ...

The 2008 language standard introduces the concept of the *unlimited-format-item*, that is a language-standard mechanism for repeating a format specification as many times as necessary.  In the olden days one might precede a format specification with a very large number (as @dave_thompson_085 mentions), now one can use a `*` instead, for example

```
write(1,'(*(e16.6))') matA
```

rather than

```
write(1,'(999(e16.6))') matA
```

Many compilers in common use already implement this feature.

Comment: We do have duplicates even with the unlimited count http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27728502/dynamic-output-format-setting/27732194