# Writting a matrix in a file in Fortran

Tags: fortran

I wanted to write a subroutine in modern fortran (90 or newer) to write the elements of a given matrix into a file output.txt. Each line of the file output.txt contains the elements of each row of the matrix (the natural).

The following is an example (of course, it is not a subrutine depending on a matrix A, is a function fix the matrix defined inside just to explain you my questions).

```
  PROGRAM testing
  !
  IMPLICIT NONE
  !
  REAL, ALLOCATABLE :: A(:,:)
  INTEGER           :: i, j, n, m
  CHARACTER(LEN=20) :: opt
  !
  m = 3
  n = 4
  !
  ALLOCATE( A(n,m))
  A(1,:) = (/  1 ,  2 ,  3 ,  4 /)
  A(2,:) = (/ -1 , -2 , -3 , -4 /)
  A(3,:) = (/ 10 , 20 , 30 , 40 /)
  !
  !
  opt = '(4(e25.15,1x))' ! <--- I NEED THE VALUE OF M INSTEAD OF 3 HERE !!!!!!
  OPEN(1, file='output.txt', status='replace', action='write')
  DO i = 1,m
     WRITE(1,opt) ( A(i,j) , j=1,n )
  END DO
  CLOSE(1)
  !
END PROGRAM testing
```

My problem is that "4" in the opt variable. I wanted to have define

```
 opt = '(4(e25.15,1x))'
```

but depending on n (the number of columns of the matrix):

```
 opt = '(n(e25.15,1x))'
```

Y tried to do a cast, something like:

```
    character :: aux(44)
    integer   :: i

    i = 3

    write (aux, "(A5,I40)") '(', i
    opt = '('//TRIM(aux)//'(e25.15,1x))'
```

but this depends on the 40. If the number of columns is too big this going to fail.

Do you know how to do this? Maybe there are a better option to write the matrix into an output file.

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran wuestions. Do not use tag [tag:fortran90] if you allow more recent ones.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format string for output dependent on a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881186/format-string-for-output-dependent-on-a-variable)  Ignore the accepted answer.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43482939/write-dynamical-arrays-in-fortran-90 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27728502/dynamic-output-format-setting

Comment: Your rows and columns look wrong. (Fortran is column major), so your allocate and 4 versus 3 and M and N need to account for column major.

Comment: That maybe true @veryreverie , however the allocate seems to imply 4 rows and 3 columns... unless I am reading it wrong?

Comment: "but this depends on the 40". As the 40 is the field width for the repeat count you desire, to have "too many columns" you would need a number of columns with more than 40 digits. That's going to cause problems long before it comes to worrying about whether your file is formatted correctly. (That would also try to write 45 characters to a character of length 44.)

Comment: Thanks!!  The solution in the other questions that you suggest me solved my problem.

Comment: [Does this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66685341/380384) help you in formatting a matrix for text output in columns?