# Arguments of different types in a same Fortran subroutine

Tags: console, fortran, fortran90

I want to define a subroutine in modern fortran (90 or newer) to print a matrix (with integer or real numbers) or vectors (with integer o numbers).

```
SUBROUTINE print_matrix_vector( A )

! WHAT TYPE CAN I WRITE TO A ???

END SUBROUTINE
```

Of course, I wanted to call a subrutine

```
CALL print_matrix_vector( A )
```

independent if A is a matrix of real or integer numbers, and if A is a vector of real or integer numbers.

Thanks in advance for your comments. I think this is something very usual, but I did not find nothing clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So Fortran uses `interface` statements to declare overloads to functions. I have done the exact same thing recently.  The key is to create an interface, I call `show` which is used as an alias for all the separate functions needed.

```
interface show
    procedure show_vector_i, show_vector_r, show_vector_d
    procedure show_matrix_i, show_matrix_r, show_matrix_d
end interface
```

Here is the output first.

```
 Display Matrices/Vectors

 vector=
    1
    2
    3
    4

 matrix=
    1    5    9   13
    2    6   10   14
    3    7   11   15
    4    8   12   16

 A=
 4.47723     3.36660     1.48809    -.752551
 6.36660     7.19091     6.67333     5.54482
 7.48809     9.67333     10.1187     9.77902
 8.24745     11.5448     12.7790     13.0861

 u=
 6.36660
 7.19091
 6.67333
 5.54482

 v=
 3.36660
 7.19091
 9.67333
 11.5448
```

and the code

```
program FortranConsole1
use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env
implicit none

interface show
    procedure show_matrix_i, show_matrix_r, show_matrix_d
    procedure show_vector_r, show_vector_d
end interface

integer :: row(16), matrix(4,4), i
real(real64), allocatable, target :: A(:,:)
real(real64), pointer :: B(:,:)
real(real64), allocatable :: v(:), u(:)

row = [(i,i=1,16)]
matrix = reshape( row, [4, 4])

print *, "Display Matrices/Vectors"
print *, ""

print *, "vector="
call show(row(1:4))

print *, "matrix="
call show(matrix)

A = dble(matrix)

A = sqrt( matmul( transpose(A), A) ) - A

print *, "A="
call show(A)

v = A(:,2)
u = A(2,:)

print *, "u="
call show(u)
print *, "v="
call show(v)
    

contains

subroutine show_vector_i(v, w)
! Display the vector 'v' in a single column
!   v : the array of real numbers
!   w : the column width. default = 5
!   s : sig. figures w-5 (calculated)
    integer, intent(in) :: v(:)
    integer, intent(in), optional :: w
    integer :: i,n,wt
    character(len=16) :: fmt
    if(present(w)) then
        wt = w
    else
        wt = 5
    end if
    n = size(v)
    write( fmt, "(a,g0,a)") "(*(g",wt,".0))"
    write( * , fmt ) ( v(i), new_line("A"), i=1,n )    
end subroutine

subroutine show_vector_r(v, w)
! Display the vector 'v' in a single column
!   v : the array of real numbers
!   w : the column width. deafult = 12
!   s : sig. figures w-5 (calculated)
    real(real32), intent(in) :: v(:)
    integer, intent(in), optional :: w
    integer :: i,n,dg,wt
    character(len=16) :: fmt
    if(present(w)) then
        wt = w
    else
        wt = 12
    end if
    dg = wt - 6
    n = size(v)
    write( fmt, "(a,g0,a,g0,a)") "(*(g",wt,".",dg,"))"
    write( * , fmt ) ( v(i), new_line("A"), i=1,n )    
end subroutine

subroutine show_vector_d(v, w)
! Display the vector 'v' in a single column
!   v : the array of real numbers
!   w : the column width. deafult = 12
!   s : sig. figures w-5 (calculated)
    real(real64), intent(in) :: v(:)
    integer, intent(in), optional :: w
    call show_vector_r(real(v),w)
end subroutine

subroutine show_matrix_i(A, w)
! Display the matrix 'A' in columns
!   A : the array of integers
!   w : the column width. Default = 5
    integer, intent(in) :: A(:,:)
    integer, intent(in), optional :: w
    integer :: i,j,n,m, wt
    character(len=16) :: fmt
    if(present(w)) then
        wt = w
    else
        wt = 5
    end if
    n = size(A,1)
    m = size(A,2)
    write( fmt, "(a,g0,a)") "(*(g",wt,".0))"        
    write( * , fmt ) ( (A(i,j),j=1,m), new_line("A"), i=1,n )
end subroutine

subroutine show_matrix_r(A, w)
! Display the matrix 'A' in columns
!   A : the array of real numbers
!   w : the column width. deafult = 12
!   s : sig. figures w-5 (calculated)
    real(real32), intent(in) :: A(:,:)
    integer, intent(in), optional :: w
    integer :: i,j,n,m,dg,wt
    character(len=16) :: fmt
    if(present(w)) then
        wt = w
    else
        wt = 12
    end if
    dg = wt - 6
    n = size(A,1)
    m = size(A,2)
    write( fmt, "(a,g0,a,g0,a)") "(*(g",wt,".",dg,"))"
    write( * , fmt ) ( (A(i,j),j=1,m), new_line("A"), i=1,n )
end subroutine

subroutine show_matrix_d(A,w)
! Display the matrix 'A' in columns
!   A : the array of dble numbers
!   w : the column width. default = 12
! Converts 'A' into single precision and calls `show_matrix_r`
    real(real64), intent(in) :: A(:,:)
    integer, intent(in), optional :: w
    call show_matrix_r(real(A),w)
end subroutine

end program FortranConsole1
```

In reality, the functions should be in a `module` file in order to be reused again and again in different programs.

Comment: Nice answer, but I think I would just note that in real code you would almost certainly out all the overloaded routines and the interface in a module and use that - internal procedures are great for examples, but their use is a bit limited.

Comment: @IanBush - yeah, where you place the functions is a design decision not considered by this answer.

Comment: I edited the answer to reflect better the spirit of the question, displaying more vectors and matrices of integer and real values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will use it just to test the code. I like to write the output to a file and read it with octave (matlab) to analyze. There it is easy do something like spy, calculate determinants...     So it is just to debug code, and then your answer is perfect. Thanks again.

Comment: Note that the `show()` calls support an optional parameter for the width of the columns to show. It defaults to 5 for integers and 12 for real numbers. Also, double precision is converted to single-precision for display since more than 5 significant figures are generally not needed for display.